# Segfault Error in Custom Dictionary Class C++

Tags: c++

So, as part of my assignment in Computer Science, which was to read tweets and put them into a custom Dictionary, I had to, you guessed it, create a dictionary. However, during testing with the dictionary, I encountered an error which I have been unable to fix, despite hours of attempted troubleshooting. I have narrowed it down, and determined that the error lies on line 144, somewhere in the statement `cout<<j.get("name").getFront()->getText();`, but I have been unable to determine which part of this causes issues, even when breaking it down by parts, except that it begins when I add in the `->getText()`, however I heavily suspect that the problem starts earlier on.

I am sorry if I am not too specific, or if I ramble too much, I have just been having trouble with this for a while, and am beginning to get frustrated.

I understand not all the execution or style is the best, so I may ask you to refrain from leaving comments on the way things are done, unless it may directly relate to the problem at hand.

Thank you for any and all help.

```
/*********************************************************************************************************************
 * [REDACTED]                                                                                                        *
 * CS 101-- Project 4 (Hashing Twitter)                                                                              *
 * This program stores Twitter posts in a hash table                                                                 *                                                                                                        *
 *********************************************************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class tweet {
    private:
        string create_at;
        string text;
        string screen_name;
    public:
        string getCreate_at() {
            return create_at;
        };
        string getText() {
            return text;
        };
        string getScreen_name() {
            return screen_name;
        };
        void setCreate_at(string c) {
            create_at=c;
        };
        void setText(string c) {
            text=c;
        };
        void setScreen_name(string c) {
            screen_name=c;
        };
};
class LinkedList {
    public:
        tweet* getFront() {
            return top;
        };
        LinkedList* getNext() {
            return next;
        };
        void setNext(LinkedList* c) {
            next = c;
        };
        void setTweet(tweet c) {
            top = &c;
        };
        void setTweet(tweet* c) {
            top = c;
        };
        void insertFront(tweet c) {
            LinkedList temp;
            temp.setTweet(top);
            temp.setNext(next);
            this->setTweet(c);
            this->setNext(&temp);
        };
        tweet* removeFront() {
            tweet* temp;
            temp = top;
            if(next != NULL){
                top = next->getFront();
                if(next->getNext() != NULL)
                    next = next->getNext();
            }
            return temp;
        };
    private:
        tweet* top;
        LinkedList* next;
};
class HashTable {
    private:
        vector<LinkedList> store [256];//access by firstcharacter of name as index of array then search through vector linearly until find key 
        LinkedList getLinkedList(string c) {
            vector<LinkedList> temp=store[(int)c.c_str()[0]];
            for(int i =0;i<temp.size();i++) {
                if(temp.at(i).getFront()->getScreen_name()==c) {
                    return temp.at(i); //gets list of tweets
                }
            };
        };
        bool keyExists(string c) {
            vector<LinkedList> temp = store[(int)c.c_str()[0]];
            for(int i =0;i<temp.size();i++) {
                if(temp.at(i).getFront()->getScreen_name()==c) {
                    return true; //gets list of tweets
                }
            };
            return false;
        };
        void insertTweet(tweet c){
            if(keyExists(c.getScreen_name())){
                getLinkedList(c.getScreen_name()).insertFront(c);
            } else {
                LinkedList temp;
                temp.setTweet(c);
                store[c.getScreen_name().c_str()[0]].push_back(temp);
            }
        };
    public:
        void put(tweet c) {
            insertTweet(c);
        };
        LinkedList get(string key) {
            return getLinkedList(key);
        };
        bool contains(string key) {
            return keyExists(key);
        };
        void remove(string key) {
            vector<LinkedList> temp=store[key.c_str()[0]];
            for(int i =0;i<temp.size();i++) {
                if(temp.at(i).getFront()->getScreen_name()==key) {
                    temp.erase(temp.begin()+i); //gets list of tweets
                }
            };
        };
};
HashTable parser(string filename) {
    //backslashes
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    tweet hello;
    hello.setText("hello");
    hello.setScreen_name("user");
    hello.setCreate_at("10211997");
    tweet heyo;
    heyo.setText("heyo");
    heyo.setScreen_name("name");
    heyo.setCreate_at("79912101");
    LinkedList jerome;
    jerome.insertFront(hello);
    cout<<jerome.getFront()->getText()<<endl;
    jerome.insertFront(heyo);
    cout<<jerome.removeFront()->getText()<<endl;
    HashTable j;
    j.put(heyo);
    cout<<j.get("name").getFront()->getText();
}
```

Comment: `store[c.getScreen_name().c_str()[0]].push_back(temp);` can be simplified to `store[c.getScreen_name()[0]].push_back(temp);` and use `std::string`'s built in `[]` operator. But before you run off and do anything like this, consider what will happen if the provided character  contains a character with a value under 0.

Comment: Same problem will occur again here: `store[key.c_str()[0]];`

Comment: Add a complete copy of the error that you are getting.

Comment: Return from `LinkedList getLinkedList(string c)` is not defined for all cases. Compiler warning picked off this one for me and should have for you as well. If not, crank up the warning level. I'm using `-pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wconversion` in g++. Addendum: returning by value will provide a copy of the linked list, not the real thing. You may want to return a reference here.

Comment: This one `store[(int)c.c_str()[0]];` almost for it right, but it need to convert to an `unsigned int` to prevent negative index values.

Comment: `std::list` and `std::unordered_map` are available already.  Any reason why you implemented your own linked list and hash table?  You're using `std::vector`, so why not use the other container classes?  `std::list<tweet>` doing that, and half your code would be no longer needed and would not contain the bug that the answer from @txmanga pointed out.

Comment: All of these are implemented because of the parameters of the assignment, @PaulMcKenzie so thank you, but this does not solve my problem.

Comment: Well, see my comment below.  You have a lot of work to do to rid yourself of storing pointers to temporaries.  You now have to manage the memory (the rule of 3 now comes into play) meaning you have to write destructors for your LinkedList class and possibly other classes.  But that still is a wonder as to why you can't use `std::list`, as your usage of containers seems arbitrary.  You use `std::vector`, but not `std::list` -- strange.  Maybe you can list exactly what you can't use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the addresses of temporaries:

```
    void insertFront(tweet c) {
        LinkedList temp;
        temp.setTweet(top);
        temp.setNext(next);
        this->setTweet(c); //should be &c, but c is a temporary!
        this->setNext(&temp); //temp is a temporary!
    };
```

Also, in HashTable, you need `put` and `insertTweet` to have a `tweet&` parameter.

Finally, still in `insertTweet`, you should pass the address of c to setTweet.

Note that this code is very fragile, as you will have dangling pointers as soon as the tweet objects go out of scope.

Comment: Oh, okay. any suggestions for how to do this without using temporaries?

Comment: Use `std::list`.  See my comment -- you're using `std::vector` now as it is.

Comment: To do this without temporaries, you have to rethink your design to use value semantics (which is what `std::list` does) or use dynamic memory allocation, thus increasing the chance of memory leaks.

Comment: Good eyes, bmanga. Problem is systemic throughout the code. @blurthe1st, Play around with a few smaller, simpler programs to get pass by value and pass by reference worked out in your head. Fixing your program will require a significant rip-up that is beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: If you are not allowed to use standard containers as @PaulMcKenzie suggested, the best option you have are smart pointers or dynamic memory allocation

Comment: Not quite true, bmanga. blurthe1st can write a smarter LinkedList.

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my problem! Also, thank you for other suggestions, I am still working on learning this language so I may not make the most effective or stylistically sound choices!

Comment: @blurthe1st What exactly solved the problem?  Unless you wrote copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor at lightning speed ... or just bit the bullet and used `std::list` or smart pointer class.  Just warning you, in case you just called `new` without calling `delete`, thus now having a program with memory leaks.

Comment: In reality it was the suggestion to make the fixes to change to tweet& and the transition to passing an address to insertTweet that fixed the code that I had, but I am also rebuilding the entire file using suggestions you guys gave me to create a more stable file in total, and that seems to be working better. It was just a bit of a lack of understanding of the language that caused this incident, really, and I am thankful for you guys' willingness to help!

Comment: @blurthe1st watch out for `getLinkedList` and `keyExists`. If they seem to be giving the correct results, it is only by pure misfortune.